# Doing a Count on Array of Objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If I have the payload:

```
{
    "objs": [
        {  "_id": "1234566", "some":"data" },
        {  "_id": "1234566", "some":"data" },
        {  "_id": "2345666", "some":"otherdata" },
        {  "_id": "4566666", "some":"yetotherdata" },
    ]
}
```

What would be the best filter to get all objects with id:  "1234566"?

Comment: the `{_id:"1234566"}` filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all the documents having the an `obj` with `_id` as `1234566`:

```
db.collection.find({"objs._id":"1234566"});
```

To filter the `obj` items, having the specified `_id`, for the document. Assuming your document has the `_id` attribute.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$objs"},
{$match:{"objs._id":"1234566"}},
{$group:{"_id":"_id","objs":{$push:{"id":"$objs._id","some":"$objs.some"}}}}, 
{$project:{"_id":0,"objs":1}}
])
```

You can change the `_id` in the `$group` stage, if you want to group based on some different field.